# How to capture HTTP headers to particular url in my Ubuntu computer?

Tags: networking, http, monitoring, sniffing, headers

I am connecting a website and can see the hearders by firefox inspect tool. I like to do it from outside of the browser for particular url acceses. How can I do it in my Ubuntu computer?

Comment: The tool you use to retrieve a URL determines what headers are sent. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to get some scheme of url addresses returned with the headers and download some file from those addresses